# Easy decision hard counting Parametrized

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

It is known that counting perfect matchings in a bipartite graph is #P-complete. On the other hand, finding a perfect matching belongs in P.
Is there a problem, that exhibits the same behavior in parametrized  complexity? (Decision in FPT and counting in #W[1] or some other counting class?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finding $k$-path (simple paths of length $k$) in a graph is in $FPT$ and can be done in [$O^*(2^k)$ with a randomized algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3026.pdf) or [$O^*(2.62^k)$ deterministically](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~hadas/PUB/REPFAM_SZ.pdf).

This is while [Counting $k$-paths is $\#W[1]$-hard](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/presentations/counting-k-paths.pdf).

---

A more interesting example (decision is even in $P$ while counting is parameterized-hard) would be counting $k$-matchings in bipartite graph.
Not only that the problem is $\#P$-complete, it was recently shown to be [$\#W[1]$-hard](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2929) as well !